# Internet Download Manager it is detectable by owner websites

Tags: google-chrome, download, web

I have a stupid question which I can't find the answer. If I download a video or a music with IDM from the site with name X, the owner can see if I downloaded the video? Is there any way to track it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the owner of the website you are downloading from can track the traffic and which files you downloaded. That doesn't necessarily mean that they does it because a system that does that will probably have to be set up manually (depending on hosting service).